# Как диагональ заполнить нулями, элементы выше главной диагонали заполнить -1 , ниже – 3?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Не получается заполнить элементы массива 4х4 выше главной диагонали и ниже:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 36, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 13, 14, 15, 16])
print("Одномерный массив: " + str(a))
print("Размерность 4х4: ")
print(a.reshape((4, 4)))

di = np.diag_indices(4)
di
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
a
a[di] = 0

print("Диагональ заполнена нулями, элементы выше главной диагонали заполнить -1,"
      " ниже – 3: ")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [np.diag_indices()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices.html?highlight=diag_indices#numpy.diag_indices), [np.triu_indices()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) и [tril_indices()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html#numpy.tril_indices):

```
N = a.shape[0]

a[np.diag_indices(N)] = 0

a[np.triu_indices(N, 1)] = -1

a[np.tril_indices(N, -1)] = -3
```

результат:

```
In [171]: a
Out[171]:
array([[ 0, -1, -1, -1],
       [-3,  0, -1, -1],
       [-3, -3,  0, -1],
       [-3, -3, -3,  0]])
```